# select all messages sent to or received by logged user without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

mysql query fetches all messages sent to or by the logged user

```html
<?

$db->query("SELECT id AS msgId, sender, receiver, message, seen, date FROM messages WHERE sender=:loggedUser OR receiver=:loggedUser ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0", array(':loggedUser'=>$loggedUser));

?>
```

The `messages` table has two foreign keys, `receiver, sender`, that both point to the user's `id` in the `users` table. I need to loop through it with these conditions:

1. if the sender != $loggedUser
       -get the sender's: `name, image` from `users` table and most recent `mesasge, seen, date` between the two from `messages` table
2. if the sender == $loggedUser
       -get the receiver's: `name, image` from `users` table and most recent `mesasge, seen, date` between the two from `messages` table

my current solution isn't the best and gets duplicates

```html
<?

$users = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT 
 s.id AS senderId, r.id AS receiverId, 
 s.name AS sender, r.name AS receiver, 
 s.image AS senderImg, r.image AS receiverImg,
 date
 FROM messages 
 LEFT JOIN users s ON s.id = messages.sender 
 LEFT JOIN users r ON r.id = messages.receiver 
 WHERE (s.id = :loggedUser OR r.id=:loggedUser)
 ORDER BY date DESC", 
 array(":loggedUser"=>$loggedUser));

$response = "[";
foreach ($users as $u) {
 # check if logged user sent msg
 if ($loggedUser == $u['senderId']) {

  $Id = $u['receiverId'];
  $Name = $u['receiver'];
  $Img = $u['receiverImg'];
  $msgDte = $db->query("SELECT message, date, seen FROM messages WHERE sender=:s AND receiver=:r ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1", array(':s'=>$loggedUser, ':r'=>$u['receiverId']));
 }
 # check if logged user received msg
 else if ($loggedUser == $u['receiverId']) {

  $Id = $u['senderId'];
  $Name = $u['sender'];
  $Img = $u['senderImg'];
  $msgDte = $db->query("SELECT message, date, seen FROM messages WHERE sender=:s AND receiver=:r ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1", array(':s'=>$u['senderId'], ':r'=>$loggedUser));
 }

 // main json
 $response .= "{";
 $response .= '"id": '.$Id.',';
 $response .= '"sender": "'.$Name.'",';
 $response .= '"image": "'.$Img.'",';
 $response .= '"message": "'.$msgDte[0]['message'].'",';
 $response .= '"seen": "'.$msgDte[0]['seen'].'",';
 $response .= '"date": "'.$msgDte[0]['date'].'"';
 $response .= "},";

}
$response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
$response .= "]";
// return json
echo $response;

?>
```

my intention here is to get a dropdown list of messages with corresponding user name, profile pic, message date and seen value like facebook messages notification dropdown menu. My query has an `OFFSET` value but would really appreciate a query with `id > x` or `id < x` to prevent slow `pagination`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?
// get start var
$start = (int)$_GET['start'];

if ($start <= 0) {
  // check if first request
  $offSet = "AND t1.id > $start";
}
else if ($start > 0) {
  // check if subsequent request
  $offSet = "AND t1.id < $start";
}

// fetch messages
$messages = $db->query("SELECT t1.id, t1.sender, t1.receiver, t1.message, t1.seen, t1.date FROM messages AS t1 LEFT JOIN messages AS t2 ON ((t1.sender = t2.sender AND t1.receiver = t2.receiver)  OR (t1.sender = t2.receiver AND t1.receiver = t2.sender)) AND t1.id < t2.id WHERE (t1.sender = :userid OR t1.receiver = :userid) AND t2.id IS NULL $offSet ORDER BY t1.date DESC LIMIT 0, 15", array(":userid"=>$userid));

// get last message id
$nofMsg = count($messages) - 1;
$lastId = $messages[$nofMsg]['id'];

// construct json
$response = "[";
$seen = 0;

foreach ($messages as $x) {
  // check if logged user hence sender
  if ($x['sender'] == $userid) {
    // get user details
    $userDetz = $db->query("SELECT id, name, image FROM users WHERE id=:id", array(':id'=>$x['receiver']));
    // set seen 
    if ($x['seen'] == 0) {
      $seen = 1;
    }
  }
  // check if logged user hence receiver
  if ($x['receiver'] == $userid) {
    // get user details
    $userDetz = $db->query("SELECT id, name, image FROM users WHERE id=:id", array(':id'=>$x['sender']));
    // set seen 
    if ($x['seen'] == 1) {
      $seen = 1;
    }
  }
  // main json
  $response .= "{";
  $response .= '"id": '.$userDetz[0]['id'].',';
  $response .= '"name": "'.$userDetz[0]['name'].'",';
  $response .= '"image": "'.$userDetz[0]['image'].'",';
  $response .= '"message": "'.$x['message'].'",';
  $response .= '"seen": "'.$seen.'",';
  $response .= '"date": "'.soshDate($x['date']).'",';
  $response .= '"lastId": '.$lastId.'';
  $response .= "},";
}

$response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
$response .= "]";
// return json
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and desired results would help.  But if you want the most recent messages between one user and any other user, then start with logic like this:

```
select m.*,
       (case when :loggedUser = m.sender
             then m.receiver else m.sender
        end) as other_id
from messages m
where :loggedUser in (m.sender, m.receiver) and
      m.date = (select max(m2.date)
                from messages m2
                where (m.sender, m.receiver) in
                          ( (m2.sender, m2.receiver),
                            (m2.receiver, m2.sender)
                          )
                );
```

This will filter down to one row per pair.  You then seem to know how to use `join` to bring in the additional information you want (such as names).

Comment: thanks i'll give this a try mean while i also found a solution